# How to simply show *.jar in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

The Intellij Idea show the External Libraries with group, version and jar, it seems too long, how to simply show aopalliance-1.0.jar on the top like in Eclipse??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not possible in IDEA.

Bear in mind that some libraries can contain multiple jars (for example expand the "<1.8>" library).

Also the dependency is defined by the group/artifact/version strings, so it makes sense to show them on the top level node.

However I agree that having exactly one node under the top level node for almost every library in the project is unnecessary and not good for usability.

So maybe the two nodes could be collapsed into a single node that shows both the jar name and the group/artifact/version string - with one of it probably grayed out a little.

I suggest you create a feature request at JetBrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA